# Simple logging to database class/toolkit for php?

Tags: php, mysql, logging

We have a PHP/MySQL application and I want to setup a logging mechanism to log all financial related actions into this table.

I was thinking of a simple file based mechanism, but due to the risk of two instances conflicting with each other, I suppose a database based mechanism would be better.

Can anyone recommend a class / toolkit that can encapsulates simple logging mechanisms, but with a database backend?

Comment: Wouldn't it be very easy to just make another table to log all transactions into the existing MySQL database?

Comment: @gnur - yup, we want to feed the logs into another table, just wondering if a decent class existed that handled different error levels, datetime logging, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want to log changes to data which is stored in a database.

Why not just use the DBMS audit tracking facilities?

(with mysql, just set up a dummy slave to consume the replication logs).

Comment: Thanks @symcbean - never thought about that before! Doing exactly that now... :)

Answer (score 4):

Try [Log4PHP](http://logging.apache.org/log4php/), it's quite flexible and support a wide range of storages for the log!

Comment: interesting, although it might be overkill... Does it handle race conditions fine?

Comment: http://logging.apache.org/log4php/docs/appenders.html. Using the db appender and a table with timestamp, could reduce it a lot. Log4PHP is derived from Log4J (Java version).

Comment: Nice to see that log4php isn't dead